# Want to move from coding to testing. Maunal testing or automation is good option?

Tags: automation

I am working as a web developer(HTMl,CSS,Javascript,XSL,XML,AJAX) from last 1 yr.
After completing 2 years , want to move in testing field.
Also have basic knowledge of JAVA.
Dont have interest in coding.
Is selenium web driver a good option for me or which tool should I move into.
Moving into testing field is a good option??

Answer (score 0):

As u said you have basic knowledge on java,so selenium have good demand in market you can go for selenium,java people can enjoy selenium,hope this helps for u.